# Ngx-socket-io Package is not work in Angular.js

Tags: node.js, angularjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I was trying to use the [`ngx-socket-io`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-socket-io) package, which does not work in Angular.js. Is there an alternative package I can use that will work in Angular?

Moddule.js:

```
import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ngx-socket-io';
 
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://localhost:8988', options: {} };
 
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SocketIoModule.forRoot(config)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

ChatService.js

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io'
 
@Injectable()
export class ChatService {
 
    constructor(private socket: Socket) { }
 
    assign_biker(biker_id){

     this.socket.emit("assign_biker_order",{'biker_id:biker_id })

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you Try  socket client angular package  ?

it so easy to use and worked in angular js.

Install first socket.io-client.

```
  npm i socket.io-client

 import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

 private socket;

constructor() { 
  this.socket = io('here is your socket url');
}


assign_biker(biker_id){
 this.socket.emit("assign_biker_order",{'biker_id:biker_id })
}
```

Comment: Yes @jayesh You are Right socket.io-client is workign  thank you for help me.

Comment: it's my pleasure